# Debugging Thunderbird on Mac OS X with GDB

Tags: macos, gdb, thunderbird

I tried today to find a bug in Thunderbird, or more specifically - the location where it crashes ( the Crash reporter jumps in ).
However when I try to run it in gdb, the program immediately exits with code 06.
And then the Crash reporter springs into action again.
This way, I can never get to the actual point where it dies.

Is there some option I have to pass to make it start successfully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to tell the loader that this is where all the shared libraries are.

First go to the MacOS directory of you .app.

```
cd blah/dist/Daily.app/Contents/MacOS
```

And then set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`
```

And finally run the `thunderbird` executable.

```
gdb thunderbird
```

It should then run properly.

This is all mentioned in the Debugging Mozilla docs: [Here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_on_Mac_OS_X#Debugging_from_the_Terminal_with_gdb)